# Issue Mocking Spring Boot Repository with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am an FEE brand new to the backend world and am building a practice project with Spring Boot. I have a service that uses a repository holding one "Admin" object with a username and password and the service has one method that validates whether the request has valid username/password for the repository. This service works when I test it with postman but for the life of me I cannot get the tests to work. I am using junit/mockito for the very first time so I think I am mocking my repository incorrectly. I have two log lines in the method of the service and looks like my test case when calling this method the repository username/password is not how I have it mocked but has the actual values of the username/password in the repository. This results in my test case failing. My goal is to have the *mocked* username/password for the repository being compared within my service class.

Here are the two log lines in my service's validateIsAdmin method:
`log.info("username and password for repository is: " + adminRepository.getAdminUserName() + " | " + adminRepository.getAdminPassword()); log.info("Recieved admin auth request with {}", adminRequest.getUsername() + " | " + adminRequest.getPassword());`

Here is the service class I am trying to test:

```
package com.couvq.readinglist.service;

import com.couvq.readinglist.dto.AdminRequest;
import com.couvq.readinglist.dto.AdminResponse;
import com.couvq.readinglist.repository.AdminRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class AdminAuthService {

    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;

    public AdminResponse validateIsAdmin(AdminRequest adminRequest) {
        log.info("username and password for repository is: " + adminRepository.getAdminUserName() + " | " + adminRepository.getAdminPassword());
        log.info("Recieved admin auth request with {}", adminRequest.getUsername() + " | " + adminRequest.getPassword());
        // if username and password of request matches that of repository, isAdmin is true
        if (adminRequest.getUsername().equals(adminRepository.getAdminUserName())
            && adminRequest.getPassword().equals(adminRepository.getAdminPassword())) {
            return AdminResponse.builder()
                    .isAdmin(true)
                    .build();
        } else {
            return AdminResponse.builder()
                    .isAdmin(false)
                    .build();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test case

```
import com.couvq.readinglist.dto.AdminRequest;
import com.couvq.readinglist.dto.AdminResponse;
import com.couvq.readinglist.repository.AdminRepository;
import com.couvq.readinglist.service.AdminAuthService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ReadingListApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private AdminAuthService adminAuthService;

    @Mock
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Test
    public void validateIsAdminWithAdminUserNameAndPasswordReturnsTrueResponse() {
        when(adminRepository.getAdminUserName()).thenReturn("username");
        when(adminRepository.getAdminPassword()).thenReturn("password");

        AdminRequest request = AdminRequest.builder()
                .username("username")
                .password("password")
                .build();

        AdminResponse response = adminAuthService.validateIsAdmin(request);

        AdminResponse expectedResponse = AdminResponse.builder()
                .isAdmin(true)
                .build();

        assertEquals(expectedResponse, response);
    }

}
```

Here is the output I got from my test assertion:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :AdminResponse(isAdmin=true)
Actual   :AdminResponse(isAdmin=false)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can correctly mock this repository?

Comment: Well, first of all, can you send us what's the message you got in `assertEquals(expectedResponse, response);`

Comment: @artsmandev sure, I updated my question above to include that assertion error.

Comment: Thanks, another one, which version of spring boot is yours? since version 2.5+ it's not necessary `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, it's already implemented by @SpringBootTest

Comment: it is version 3.0.0, I added that @ExtendWith annotation when googling trying to find a solution. Seems that is something I can remove then.

Comment: yes, you can. in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) will see that it already uses @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stick with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) and replace @Autowired with @InjectMocks. This will inject your mock repository class into the service.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `@SpringBootTest` - the whole `Application Context` is bootstrapped, including the `AdminRepository` and `AdminAuthService` beans. If the test was a simple unit test, using the `@Mock` would be enough. But since it is an integration test, and the `AdminAuthService` is autowired into the test, we expect that the `AdminRepository` is injected into the `AdminAuthService` as well. To have the dependency injection working and being able to mock the `AdminRepository` we need to use the following:

```java
@MockBean
AdminRepository adminRepository;
```

Furthermore, once you do this, the `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` becomes redundant.